# How can I join these two edges together?

Tags: modeling, faces, edges

[image][image][image]How can I join this cylindrical edge to this cube edge? (Edges are highlighted)

[image]u7.jpg

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure both halves have the same number of vertices. It looks like your barrel is a little over-complicated, so I suggest you drop a few vertices there, and maybe add a few on the other side.

Comment: While this did work, it didnt look how I wanted it too, or rather the two edges didnt blend well at all

Comment: Can you show us your next version?

Comment: Ive added two new images, it looks relatively ok but im trying to get it to look as good as possible

Comment: How does the original gun look like?